# Can't parse a json - org.json.JSON.typeMismatch

Tags: android, json

I'm getting JSONException when trying to parse the following json.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22928439/10.json

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
```

data is the full string from the json file.

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not a `JSONArray` format, it's `JSONObject`, so you should try the following:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
```

The example of `JSONArray`:

```
[
     { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
     { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
]
```

Example of `JSONObject`:

```
{
     "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "age": 25,
     "address" : {
         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
         "city": "New York",
         "state": "NY",
         "postalCode": "10021"
     },
     "phoneNumber": [
         { "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },
         { "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }
     ]
}
```